# Se puede mejorar la precisión del GPS del computador al usar Maps Javascript API de google maps?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, gps

He venido haciendo diferentes pruebas con la geolocalización de google maps en la PC, pero en ciertas PCs da un margen de error de casi 350 metros, he buscado en todo lado pero lo único que encuentro es que es por problema de navegadores desactualizados o conexión a internet, alguien me puede ayudar corroborando esta información o dando una solución para este inconveniente, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún sistema GPS instalado en el PC? La geolocalización en navegadores de PC (sin dispositivos GPS) se realiza mediante la IP pública asignada al router o modem de tu proveedor de Internet. Es diferente en un móvil que si trae un dispositivo GPS integrado o que su ubicación puede ser calculada mediante triangulación de la red de servicio a la que se conecta.

Comment: Respuesta rápida: no. Explicación: no todas las computadoras traen un GPS. Las IPs son las que te dan la geolocalización. En una aplicación móvil sí puedes tener mayor precisión por efectos de la antena GPS del dispositivo.

Comment: Por esta razón, en ordenadores o PC's sin dispositivo GPS, la precisión de la misma dependerá de una tabla de búsqueda en alguna Base de Datos que establece una relación entre la IP pública y una localización, la cual puede variar en precisión, desde una región geográfica tan amplia como un país hasta una precisión más exacta como una calle o incluso una casa o edificio específico. Más información en [Gelocation Accuracy](https://www.storelocatorwidgets.com/blogpost/20453/Everything_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_HTML5_Geolocation_Accuracy). Saludos

Comment: Respondiendole a Mauricio Contreras, no tengo un sistema GPS en la PC

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, ahora entiendo mucho mejor el tema de porque en mi PC la exactitud de mi ubicación tiene un margen de error enorme, les agradezco mucho por su tiempo y sus respuestas.